# Разбивка строки после А, В, И, К, О, С, У, Я

Tags: орфография

Какие есть правила правильного (с точки зрения книжной вёрстки) разбиения на строки возле однобуквенных слов?

Мне представляется, что запрещено оставлять на предыдущей строке только заглавные А, В, И, К, О, С, У, Я. Но многие верстальщики утверждают и то, что это правило касается строчных букв тоже. Неужели при этом «а я и у Васи» должно сливаться воедино? Или тут только «у Васи» лепится воедино?

Есть ли в этом необходимость? И какие авторитетные источники это правило подтверждают?

И обязательно ли прилеплять частицу «ж» к предыдущему слову?

Comment: Слыхом не слыхивала ни о каких авикосуях. Может найдете вразумительную трактовку хоть в каком-то варианте?  -------- Вообще правила верстки - вещь весьма косвенно относящаяся к русскому языке. А в правилах русского никаких авикосуев нет.

Comment: Правила переносов относятся к русскому языку? Наверное, и другие правила разбиения на строки тоже можно отнести к русскому языку.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не о русском языке, а о сугубо типографских правилах.

Comment: *Правила переносов относятся к русскому языку?* - Да. Они разобраныв своде правил и орфографии и пунктуации. *Наверное, и другие правила разбиения на строки тоже можно отнести к русскому языку* - нет. Нельзя расширительно толковать свод правил.

Comment: Нормальная вёрстка должна устранять «подвеску» предлога или союза на строке. Смысл прозрачен — почтение к читателю, и он же диктует такое действие с  любой частицей. Но к русскому языку, действительно, вопрос не относится.

Answer (score 2):

Правило, оказывается, несколько иное.

Если верить П.Г.Гиленсону, его «Справочнику технического и художественного редакторов» (1988 год), п. 11.4.1.1, стр. 422, то:

> В книжных изданиях не следует оставлять в конце строки предлоги и
>   союзы, начинающие предложение, а также однобуквенные союзы и предлоги
>   в середине предложений. В журнальных, газетных, информационных
>   изданиях и изданиях оперативной полиграфии допускается оставлять в
>   конце строки однобуквенные предлоги и союзы внутри предложений, а
>   также трехбуквенные предлоги, начинающие предложение.

То есть правило запрещает в конце строки оставлять не то что «А», но и «Не» и даже «Вследствие». Вот для справки списки [союзов](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B) и [предлогов](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8).

Answer (score 1):

В общем так.
Во всем интернете нашлось всего несколько упоминаний об этом волшебном слове - и только одно более или мнение по теме вопроса.

> В предпоследнем из этих примеров мы поставили неразрывный пробел,
>   поскольку согласно отечественным полиграфическим правилам строка не
>   должна начинаться с тире, а в последнем — потому что *однобуквенное
>   слово, начинающее предложение, не должно стоять последним в строке*.

http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1137/137/lecture/3829?page=2

(Курсив мой, ИГ)

Источник, конечно, совершенно не авторитетный, но с такой постановкой я готова согласиться. И там однозначно сказано, что речь идёт не просто об  одиночной заглавной букве, а о том, что с неё начинается предложение.

Ни о каких *строчных* авикосуях нет даже упоминания.

Всё остальное (включая "правило" насчет частицы ж) - скорее всего не более чем самодеятельность издательства или типографии. Иногда в чем-то разумная, но все равно - самодеятельность.